# Как можно улучшить участок кода?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, я только начинаю погружаться в мир разработки, хотелось спросить совета, как можно улучшить следующий код:

```
JobKind jobKind = 0;
foreach (JobKind value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JobKind)))
{
    var enumIntValue = (int)value;

    if (model.JobKinds.Contains(enumIntValue.ToString()))
    {
        var checkedSymbol = char.Parse(enumIntValue.ToString());
        if ((model.JobKinds.LastIndexOf(checkedSymbol) - model.JobKinds.IndexOf(checkedSymbol)) == 0)
        jobKind = jobKind | value;
    }
}
```

`JobKind` - это перечисление с атрибутом `[Flags]`. На вход идет модель, которая содержит строковое поле - типы специальностей. Там идет перечисление. Для удобства, можно указать числами наборы специальностей (например, `2,4,5`). Цифры равны значению полей в перечислении. Данный код, формирует битовое поле и перечисления из строки. Я не нашел, как можно сконвертировать строку вида `2,4,5` в перечисление более элегантным способом, по этому хотелось бы спросить вашего совета по улучшению читаемости кода и т.д.

Comment: какой тип у `model.JobKinds`? и пример значение этого поля

Comment: Это string, туда заносятся числа, например 2,4,8 - номера полей перечисления JobKinds.

Comment: ох-ох-ох, как думаешь, если у тебя в строке будет одно число 32, что вернет Contains когда ты передашь значение `2`?

Comment: Ага, вот тут я точно пролетел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае лучше не проходиться по всем значениям перечисления, а организовать свертку строки.

Для этого нужно разбить ее по разделителю `,`, с помощью функции [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx), а затем свернуть, например воспользовавшись методом [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var jobKind  = model.JobKinds.Split(',')
    .Aggregate((J)0, (acc, cur) =>
    {
        var value = (J)int.Parse(cur); // приводим элемент из строки в число, и затем в значение enum
        return acc | value; // объединяем значения и возвращаем
    });
```

Немного более компактно вызов [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) может выглядеть так:

```
.Aggregate((J)0, (acc, cur) => acc | (J)int.Parse(cur))
```

Comment: Действительно, спасибо

Comment: @PlayGroundLegend Выберите этот ответ как принятый, если он вам подошёл.